# Access root domain from subdomain on hosted apache server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, configuration, web-hosting

I had a domain: 
`mydomain.com`
pointing to a hosted apache server 'premium' account that can host multiple domains.
I bought another domain: `anotherDomain.com` which I set up as an 'add on' domain with my web host.  I can access the anotherDomain in several different ways:

```
mydomain.com/anotherDomain.com
anotherDomain.mydomain.com
```

and

```
anotherDomain.com
```

However, only when using the first method can I access 'generic' files on `mydomain.com` from `anotherDomain.com` (using relative addressing).

I was told there is a script I can write so `anotherDomain.com` can access 'root' files at `mydomain.com`, using relative addressing, but they cannot tell me how to do it.  I've looked around the net, but although there are lots of similar sounding questions, I cannot find how to do it.

Just to restate the problem: I want to be able to access files in `mydomain.com`, just like I can when `anotherDomain.com` is accessed like: `mydomain.com/anotherDomain.com`, when it is accessed like: `anotherDomain.mydomain.com` or `anotherDomain.com`

**Example:**
If I access `anotherDomain.com` using the URL `mydomain.com/anotherDomain.com` then, in the `index.html` for `anotherDomain.com` I can have:

```
<img src='../imgs/generic.jpg'/>
```

Which access the 'generic' image in the `imgs` folder for `mydomain.com`.  Unfortunately, when I access this page using the URLs:  `anotherDomain.mydomain.com` or `anotherDomain.com`, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I assume you don't have access to your server's config files and thus have to deal with the restricted possibilities of `.htaccess`. If you *have* access there would be much better ways to handle this.

I would suggest to circumvent the problem. Have a look at the other answers and the comments. You went for a highly complex setup. You might get that working, but it will be a pain in the ass in the long run.

I will elaborate a bit and explain a few things in my answer.

As I understand you have the following file structure on your server:

```
public_html/
|
+-- index.html           // the index of mydomain.com
|
+-- imgs/
|   |
|   +-- generic.jpg
|
+-- anotherDomain.com/
    |
    +-- index.html       // index of anotherDomain.com
```

Suppose you browse `http://anotherDomain.com/`.
When the browser tries to load `generic.jpg` it will create this URL: `http://anotherDomain.com/../imgs/generic.jpg`. This will, however, by almost every browser, be rewritten as `http://anotherDomain.com/imgs/generic.jpg`.

So you have to tell the server how to server this file.

- You can create a rule as @anubhava suggests. If you access `http://anotherDomain.com/imgs/*` redirect it to the `imgs` dir on the virtual host `http://mydomain.com/`. This way the content will appear to belong to `mydomain.com`.
- I would suggest creating a symlink instead, if you have the possibility.

  ```
  |
  +-- anotherDomain.com/
      |
      +-- index.html       // index of anotherDomain.com
      |
      +-- imgs --> ../imgs/
  ```

  This way you can access all the images easily. However, they will appear as content of `anotherDomain.com`. This can be seen as advantages or as already mentioned as disadvantage (search engines.) Creating a symlink can also sometimes be done by using PHP (`symlink` function) if your provider does not support it via its interface.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't choose how my webhost sets up my domains.  I would like to mirror what I have on my local machine, where I am able to create/use generic shared files.  I _really like_ the idea of creating a symlink folder.  Seems like a *totally perfect* solution.  *Unfortunately* there does not seem to be a way to do this using the interfaces provided by my web host. :...(

Comment: You could try to use PHP's file system function `symlink` ;) Sometimes it works.

Comment: And depending on the money you spent: Usually good providers have support for their customers. Are you sure you can't persuade them to edit your virtual host configuration?

Comment: I tried `<?php
$target = '../js';
$link = 'genericJS';
if(symlink($target, $link))echo 'it worked!<br>';
else echo 'it failed!';
echo readlink($link);
?>`

Comment: Oh, and it said it worked!  Also, `http://anotherDomain.com/genericJS/` lists the folder contents OK, so this seems to be superfine! :-D

Comment: Think about adding this info to your answer.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy I could help you. I've added the note on PHP to the answer.

Comment: Thinking through the security implications of this is clearly something my web host has not done...  Not sure if I should tell them or not.

Comment: :D You could just try to access another host's files. Maybe the setup is correct and you can't access files outside your root dir.

Answer (score 2):

After wasting time trying to do this with `.htaccess` files, I finally worked out a way to do it in plain old `html`.  In the header, before all other links, put:

```
<base href="http://mydomain.com/anotherDomain.com" />
```

And thats it.  Remove this for development on your local machine. ;-)
Remember to [be a bit careful when using the base tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag).

**Edit:**
I've found this causes other problems.  For example, relative links go to `http://mydomain.com/anotherDomain.com`, rather than `http://anotherDomain.com`.
Adding `.htaccess` code to the `http://mydomain.com` root directory like:

```
RedirectMatch /anotherDomain.com(/)?$ http://anotherDomain.com
```

Solves this, but introduces other problems.  Still looking for a good answer to this question...  Anybody?

Comment: +1 for your answer. I wanted to take a shot at .htaccess rules but somehow I couldn't get clear understanding of your problem. Can you explain your problem with more details and examples please.

Comment: Hi @anubhava.  I've added an example to the question as you requested.

Comment: @anubhava.  I *think* rewriting `anotherDomain.com` as `mydomain.com/anotherDomain.com` *should* work, but I have not had success with this myself.

Comment: So I think your `pulic_html/img` and `pulic_html/anotherDomain.com` folders are at same level right? Also DOCUMENT_ROOT for `anotherDomain.com` is also `pulic_html/anotherDomain.com/` is that correct?

Comment: Yes. `root.php` `<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];?>` outputs `/[..]/public_html/anotherDomain.com`

Comment: Ok so since you img dir is `/[..]/public_html/img` and your DOCUMENT_ROOT is `/[..]/public_html/anotherDomain.com` therefore img dir cannot be accessed from `http://aotherDomain.com` since it not side its DOCUMENT_ROOT tree.

Comment: @anubhava.  I just checked though, and *I am actually doing this currently*, using the `base` tag, as described in my answer.  That part is working fine.

Comment: Yes that is correct using `<base href="http://mydomain.com/anotherDomain.com" />` it will work since it prefixes `http://mydomain.com/anotherDomain.com` to all your images URLs. However as I explained there is no way to access these images using `http://anotherDomain.com` domain since `img` folder is out of bound for it (being outside DOCUMENT_ROOT).

Comment: @anubhava Typing `http://anotherDomain.com` into the address bar currently works OK, due to the `<base>` tag.  Only problem is with relative links displaying `http://mydomain.com/anotherDomain.com`.  Are you saying that there is no solution using `.htaccess` rewrite rules as `anotherDomain.com` cannot be rewritten as `mydomain.com/anotherDomain.com`?

Comment: Ok try my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your `public_html/anotherDomain.com/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# for images only
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?anotherDomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(imgs/.+)$ http://mydomain.com/anotherDomain.com/$1 [L,NC,R]

# or for all files
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?anotherDomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/anotherDomain.com/$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Remove (or comment out) your `<base...` tag.

Comment: I confirmed this doesn't work.  What you are saying here--I think--is, rewrite `anotherDomain.com/imgs/...` as `mydomain.com/imgs/...` which is not what I wanted :-(  Thanks very much for trying though :-)

Comment: But that is exactly you're doing via your `<base...` tag i.e. accessing `anotherDomain.com/imgs/` using `<base href="http://mydomain.com/anotherDomain.com" />`

Comment: Not quite :-).  With the base tag, `./imgs` is still `mydomain.com/anotherDomain.com/imgs` (same as `anotherDomain.com/imgs`).  The helpful thing about this tag is that `../imgs` refers to `mydomain.com/imgs`.  I did test out your solution, following your instructions, just in case.

Comment: I am little confused. I thought `imgs` is real folder directly under `http://mydomain.com/` and at the same level as `anotherDomain.com/` folder? Is that not correct?

Comment: Perhaps something like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)anotherDomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/anotherDomain.com$1 [L,NC,R]` would be equivalent?

Comment: Yes I was also going to say same based on your comments. Please try out edited answer..

Comment: Yes, I have `mydomain.com/imgs` but also `anotherDomain.com/imgs` the whole `mydomain.com/imgs` thing is just an *example* of a generic resource.  In fact, I have generic `js` and `php` files.  (I did add these to your code when testing).

Comment: Oh so you have 2 imgs folders one directly under `http://mydomain.com/` and another directly under `http://anothermydomain.com/`

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like this works.  I did replace my relative urls with absolute ones, so will have to do further testing, but expect it will be fine!  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry :-( when initially testing this, I looked by mistake at the `localhost` site.  When I actually test it, it doesn't work :-( Example: `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://anotherDomain.com/js/utilities.js"`

Comment: When you directly enter `http://www.anotherDomain.com/js/utilities.js` in your browser does it not go to: `http://mydomain.com/anotherDomain.com/js/utilities.js` in your browser? Another mistake I made by not making `www.` optional (please see latest edit)

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the same content via several different domains is maybe not a great idea. This can make your content appear like duplicated contents from search engines. If you keep that idea you should at least try to register all your contents with a [canonical url](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en) metatag or attribute.

Now I usually like relative urls, as always preficing url with the domain makes them harder to reuse via proxys (but when using ajax stuff, for example, relative url are not enough, you'll always end with some absolute url in some places). But here you use relative url with `'../imgs/generic.jpg'`. It means this url refers more to the way you've been putting the files on your server than to something which is meaningful. It could be meaningfull on a single domain, but to share stuff between domains it's not. What if some day you need to move the new domain files and directory root on another place (on another server?). From the user (and bots and search engines) your domains are not related. Any proxy that you do not own would request the asset several time if it is asked via `subdomain.mydomain.com/foo.jpg` and `subdomain.com/foo.jpg`, so trying to share this stuff from your domains is not meaningful for the rest of the web, it's just for your own managment, on your side. So feel free to make it simple to manage.

You'd better manage your url in a way where the url means something to you, like  `'/common/imgs/generic.jpg'` and `'/site/imgs/custom.jpg'`. Then on the domain Virtualhosts, server-side, you can work on the mapping `url->directory & files`. This mapping can be set via `Alias`, `AliasMatch`, and of course `mod_rewrite` directives.

For example a simple

```
Alias /common /path/to/mydomain/assets
```

Would allow you to map all the mydomain.com assets on the Virtualhost containing this instruction. The day you will decde to move all the things on your webserver you'll simply have to rework the apache rewrites and alias, and not all you code url management.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately I am using a commercial web hosting service, and I don't have access to Apache configuration, and `Alias` cannot be used in `.htaccess` files.

Comment: Yes, but mod_rewrite can do the same and even more. The basic usage of a `RewriteRule` is usually the same job as the stuff done by `Alias`. Mapping a query path to a filesystem path.